# Successful checkbox array for image names, but now display images in email output?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am able to successfully pass an array of checkbox values to a PHP processing page which then emails an HTML email to a specified email address.

The values are actually names of images. So, the email is currently outputting the names of the images, i.e. "cat.png, dog.png, bird.png". I would like to now have these as HTML img references. So, I would like it to print:

```
<img src="cat.png" style="border-right:1px solid #CCC;"><img src="dog.png" style="border-right:1px solid #CCC;"><img src="bird.png" style="border:none;">
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
    $Image_Style = '<img src="images/"' . $_REQUEST['Image_Style'] . ' style="border-right:1px solid #CCC;">';
```

Any ideas how I could make HMTL image calls and have it display the image in my email?

HTML FORM PAGE

```
    <input name="Image_Style[]" type="checkbox" id="newcheck2" value="cat.png" />
    <input name="Image_Style[]" type="checkbox" id="newcheck2" value="dog.png" />
    <input name="Image_Style[]" type="checkbox" id="newcheck2" value="bird.png" />
```

PHP PROCESS PAGE - Variables

```
    $Image_Style = $_REQUEST['Image_Style'];

    $Image_Style_Array = "";

    for ($i=0;$i<count($Image_Style);$i++) { 
        $Image_Style_Array .= $Image_Style[$i];
        if ($i<count($Image_Style)-1) { 
                 $Image_Style_Array .= ", ";
        }
    }
    // echo $Image_Style_Array;
```

PHP PROCESS PAGE - Send Email

```
    <tr><td>Image Style: </td><td>' . $Image_Style_Array .  '</td></tr>
```

Comment: For an array, it's usually easier to iterate over it using `foreach($array as $key => $value)` or simply `foreach($array as $value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
$Image_Style_Array = "";
foreach ($Image_Style as $image) { 
    $Image_Style_Array .= '<img src="images/' . $image . '" style="border-right:1px solid #CCC;">';
```